# Parsing XSL file using htmlagilitypack or system.xml

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, html-agility-pack, xmldocument

I have the following part of an XSL file:

```xslt
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="US-ASCII" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"/>

<!-- Defined parameters (overrideable) -->
<xsl:param name="showData" select="'n'"/>

<!--other templates-->

<xsl:template name="pageHeader">
<h1>Load Test Results</h1>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left"/>
        <td align="right">
    </tr>
</table>
<hr size="1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="testOptions">
<h2><a id="test_options">Test options</a></h2>
<table class="details" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="26%">
    <tr valign="top">
        <th align="left">Id</th>
        <th align="left">Number of Users</th>
        <th align="left">Rampup</th>
        <th align="left">Loop count</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="role">#</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14 s</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr size="1"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to change values from the testOptions template second tr tag (13, 14, 15).  How can I do that using HtmlAgilityPack or System.Xml?

So far I have:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\jmeter-results-detail.xsl");
var x = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//tr");

foreach(HtmlNode link in  x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(link.OuterHtml);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this XSLT? It doesn't seem to be doing anything with its input, or anything at all besides outputting static HTML. If that's the case, why are you using XSLT at all instead of just some HTML?

Comment: I'm using this XSLT to generate an HTML report with ant.